# Discord.js : Can't read "MessageEmbed" properties after message.channel.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

With my bot, I send an embed message and I want to be able to get a lot of properties but I call it wrong. When I do a "console.log" after sending I have all properties, but can't access to it with other methods.

I think I'm stuck in the "message.channel.XXXXX" call and I can't reach "MessageEmbed.length" etc... How can I do it if my event is "message" and everything follow "message.XXXX" class?

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content === '!sendembed') {
  const exampleEmbed = {
   color: 16711600,
   title: '__TITLE EMBED MESSAGE__',
   // a lot of fields...
  };
  message.channel
   .send({ embed: exampleEmbed })
   .then(console.log(`lenght:${message.embeds.MessageEmbed.length}`));
 }
});
```

And of course, I have an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageEmbed` is not a property of `message.embeds`. Instead, use `message.embeds[0]`, as `message.embeds` returns an `array` of embeds.

Also, `length` is not a property of `embed`, so that will return an error.

---

After realizing I misunderstood the question, here is my new solution. `message.channel.send()` returns a `Promise` of the message sent that you can use in a callback.

```js
message.channel.send({ embed: exampleEmbed }).then((msg) => {
   // gain full access to Message object
   console.log(msg.channel);
   console.log(msg.author);

   // get access to MessageEmbed object
   console.log(msg.embeds[0])
   console.log(msg.embeds[0].title.length);
};
```

Comment: I know, but how can I access to the message embed properties like .length and other after this command :

`message.channel.send({ embed: exampleEmbed });`

I want to have access to properties of this : https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood. I edited my answer with a more appropriate solution.